# Building Chilkat with a .sh file

Tags: c++, bash, shell

I downloaded chilkat and I need to build it... I got 2 .sh files. The README says:

`To build the C and C++ samples, first edit the c_sampleBuild.sh and 
linkSample.sh scripts and set the "-L" option's path for the system libraries.`

LinkSample.sh:

```
g++ -Wl,--enable-auto-import linkSample.cpp -o"linkSample.exe" -L. -libchilkat-9.5.0 -L/c/MinGW/lib -lcrypt32 -lws2_32 -ldnsapi
```

c_sampleBuild.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash -ev

gcc -c c_Sample.c -o"c_Sample.o"

g++ c_Sample.o -o"c_Sample.exe" -L. -lchilkat-9.5.0 -L/c/MinGW/lib -lcrypt32 
-lws2_32 -ldnsapi
```

It's now clear how I should make that.... Help please :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what platform you are building on. But if you are using Windows + MinGW then:

The libraries for crypt32, ws2_32 and dnsapi can be downloaded from: [here](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/downloads_vcpp.asp)

For the g++ command, the -l (lowercase) option tells g++ which additional libraries you want to link against, and the -L (uppercase) option is used to tell g++ where to look for the libraries.

If you have a library file called libbar.a in the current folder (.) then you add the option (-L. -lbar)

Or, if you have a library in /path/to/foo/libbar.a then you add (-L/path/to/foo -lbar).

You will need to check the MinGW documentation for the locations of the system libraries, they are likely to be found in /lib or /usr/lib.